# nginx gzip does not compress css/js files with a version number

Tags: nginx, gzip

So I have enabled gzip in nginx config file like following:

```
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/rss+xml
    image/svg+xml;
```

everything works fine except for those css/js files with a version number like
some-css-file.css?v=abcdefg, or some-js-file.js?v=12345

files like these are just not been compressed. Seems nginx recognize the files by  extensions(path/url) not by the "true" MIME types?
Any ideas? thanks in advance.

Comment: What content-type are these URIs returned with?

Comment: these are just ordinary css and javascript files, except ended with a version number, if I removed the version number, it get compressed as expected.